# React bootstrap navbar need guidance

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I'm learning react bootstrap, I wrote in the terminal npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap. and I got this code:
But it doesn't show it and I don't get any errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
import {Container, Nav} from "react-bootstrap";

const Navbar = () => {
    return(
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

I don't get any errors, so I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Where is Navbar coming from? And why is your own component also called Navbar?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're importing your `<Navbar>` component into your `App.js` file.

```
import Navbar from 'filelocation'
```

And create the component in the `App` component.

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I already did this but it still doesn't work. I'm clueless.

Comment: try `npm update` to update your project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like

```js
import { Container, Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function YourComponent() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

You never import Navbar, which you use in `<Navbar...`.

> Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-grothendieck-zwjjhn?file=/src/App.js:23-573

---

#### Aside

Don't name your components the same as your imports (your IDE should be showing you these as errors anyway).